# Polymer: Transfer data between sibling pages(elements)

Tags: polymer

I need help by transferring data between two sibling elements of the polymer app. I can't make one of them to be the parent so that I can use dispatchEvent for the transfer of these elements.

Is there any way to transfer data between two sibling elements in polymer?

Comment: Please add your codes how you want to use this. Also, check this that whether give you an answer your need or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803316/linking-2-custom-elements-through-parent/48813465#48813465

Answer (score 1):

Of course, for example you can use DataBinding:

```
<some-element param="{{value}}"></some-element>
<another-element param="{{value}}"></another-element>
```

In these elements you can change this "value" param and it will be changed in another one:

```
<script>
class ... 
 changeParam(){
this.param="newValue";
}
</script>
```

Another way is using events. But you don't need to dispatch it. For example:

```
class ....
static get properties(){
 return {
  prop:{
   type: Object,
   value: {},
   notify: true // (*)
 }
}
```

In line with * you can see notify property. It fires event "prop-changed" when, as you could figure out, prop changes. So you can addEventListener for this event. 
Note: somePropertyWhichCanBeChanged changes to some-property-which-can-be-changed-changed event.

Comment: And where do you call your functions?

Comment: and i recommend you read this:
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-binding
and this:
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/properties

Comment: I have on-click functions in template

Comment: This data binding works now, but i would really love to see full example of  the second solution.  never heard for this kind of approach in data transfer

Comment: Hmmm, right now i don't have an IDE, but it should work something like this.
class ...
ready(){
super.ready();
this.addEventListener('event-value-changed', function(e){
        console.log("Receiving value...");
    });
}

another element
class ...
static get properties(){
 return {
  eventValue:{
   type: Object,
   value: {},
   notify: true // (*)
 }
}
change(){
this.eventValue="newValue"
}

Comment: That is exactly what i tried, but unfortunetly it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
<my-view1 name="view1" param="{{value}}"></my-view1>
      <my-view2 name="view2" param="{{value}}"></my-view2>
```

VIEW1:

```
static get properties(){

    return {
        eventValue: {
            type: String,
            value: "Mirza",
            notify: true
        }
    }
  }

  changeParam(){
    this.param = "Azrim";
    this.eventValue = "Mirzoni";
    console.log("Param in view1: " + this.param);
    console.log("EventValue in view1: " + this.eventValue);
  }
```

VIEW2:

```
static get is() { return 'my-view2'; }


  seeParam(){
    console.log("Param in view2: " + this.param);
    this.addEventListener('event-value-changed', function(e){
        console.log("Receiving value...");
    });
  }
```